# How do I set up the buttons that are linked to didPressNumber to add to each other when pressed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

How do I set up the buttons that are linked to didPressNumber to add to each other when pressed so lets say its a calculator and I want set it up where each button is pressed has a letter and number value when it is pressed it adds to the previous one press and I want to set up 2 labels one displaying the number value and one displaying the letter value and how would I set up the value of each number?

```
enum modes {
    case not_set
    case addition
    case subtraction
    case equals
}

@IBAction func didPressNumber(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let stringValue:String? = sender.titleLabel?.text

    if (lastButtonWasMode) {
        lastButtonWasMode = false
        labelString = "0"
    }

    labelString = labelString.appending(stringValue!)
    updateText()
}

func updateText() {
    guard let labelInt:Int = Int(labelString) else {
        return
    }

    if (currentMode == .not_set) {
        savedNum = labelInt
    }

    let formatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
    let num:NSNumber = NSNumber(value: labelInt)
    label.text = formatter.string(from: num)
}

func changeMode(newMode:modes) {
    if (savedNum == 0) {
        return
    }

    currentMode = newMode
    lastButtonWasMode = true        
}
```